# Что такое "русский ФОС"?

Tags: аббревиатуры

Был такой вопрос "[Русский ФОС помогите](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447241/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%A4%D0%9E%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5)". Судя по вопросу, ФОС — всем известная аббревиатура. Помогите восполнить пробел в образовании.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что имелось в виду вот это:  ФОС – [фонд оценочных средств](http://rsuh.ru/upload/main/quality/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%20%D0%9E%D0%9F.pdf).

> Фонд оценочных средств – это комплект методических и контрольных
>   измерительных материалов, предназначенных для определения уровня
>   сформированности компетенций, оценивания знаний, умений, владений
>   обучающихся на разных стадиях обучения, а также выпускников Института
>   на соответствие (или несоответствие) уровня их подготовки требованиям
>   соответствующего федерального государственного образовательного
>   стандарта (далее – ФГОС) по завершению освоения образовательной
>   программы (далее – ОП).

[Петерсон Л.Г. Алгебра. 9 класс. Учебник. В двух частях. ФОС (количество томов: 2)](https://books.academic.ru/book.nsf/87732293/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0.+9+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81.+%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA.+%D0%92+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85+%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%85.+%D0%A4%D0%9E%D0%A1+%28%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%3A+2%29)
Литература. 9 класс. Тетрадь для контрольных работ. ФОС, Ланин Б.А.
[ФОС по русскому языку](https://multiurok.ru/files/fos-po-russkomu-iazyku.html)